# Select area of same values in 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have 2D array for example like this:

```
1 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1
```

Now if I choose random position for example position [4, 2], I would like to get array like this:

```
X X X X X
0 0 X X X
X 0 X 0 X
0 0 0 X X
0 0 0 0 X
```

Any ideas for this algorithm? No matter in which language. I just need the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a flood fill algorithm here. So, given a point, you need to check left, top, right and bottom and the diagonals and if they are of the same value, recurse (or put it into the queue)

```
public void fill(int i, int j, int value) {
  if(checkSameValue(i, j, value) {
    mark(i, j);    
  } else {
    return;
  }
  if(insideBounds(i, j-1, value)) {
    fill(i, j-1, value);
  }
  //Similarly for top, right and bottom and diagonals
}
```

Implement using a queue to prevent StackOverFlow errors. **BTW** this is just an implementation of the flood fill algorithm, you need to modify it a tiny bit for your case. Don't want to deprive you of all the fun :)